# make Field Automatically Update After A Certain AMount of Time

Tags: mysql

I have a table in my database that has a field called "end_date" of type datetime and a field called "current" of type tinyint.  Is it possible to make the table automatically update current from 1 to 0 when the datetime for "end" is reached:?  Thanks.

Comment: You need a running job to get the functionality you desire -- the date must be constantly checked before the update is made.

Comment: Since you are using a field anyway (instead of moving to another table etc), how about using the `end_date` itself where you need to check `current`? Like `... WHERE NOW() < end_date ...`, instead of `... WHERE current = 1 ...`.

Answer (score 0):

I have to agree with OMG Poines (love the name). You should probably create a script or some other job that checks the value in the database at your defined interval. The job should check the date, and if the end is reached, the job will need to set the value to 0.